# display a field based on a checkbox button

Tags: symfony

I have an add form and I want to add a field that will be visible unless if the previous field is checked (it is checkbox type), 
the two fields belong to different tables that have a one to one relationship and I work under symfony4

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('nom')
            ->add('prenom')
            ->add('dateNaissance', BirthdayType::class)
            ->add('email', EmailType::class)
            ->add('profession')
            ->add('typePieceIdentite', ChoiceType::class, [
                  'choices'  => ['Carte National'=>'Carte National'  ,
                                 'Permi de conduire' =>'Permi de conduire',
                                 'Passeport' =>'Passeport',]])
            ->add('numPiece')
            ->add('aUnVehicule', CheckboxType::class)
            ->add('vehicule', VehiculeType::class)


        ;
    }
```

Comment: It may be better to just hide your "vehicule" input while the checkbox is false, and just display it when the user selected it. Be sure to control your form in the controller to not have the CheckboxType to true but no VehiculeType.

Comment: you probably won't get around javascript somewhere to make it user-friendly ...